# Domain registar no longer exists

Tags: domain, domain-registrar, domain-registration

I came to this company and they already had a domain registered with SharpRegister.com. That website no longer exists. Our domain is still active and working, but we need to ensure that it continues to work going forward. I've never dealt with anything like this before. I've reached out to the registered owner of the website, but I'm wondering if there is a technical way that we can handle this. We own the domain, is there some way of releasing it without using the GUI that should be provided by the Registar?

Comment: Check the Who Is  information for the registrar, and see if that gives you any updated info. See if anyone has alternative contact info. Otherwise I would expect you would have to wait for expiration and repurchase. Is the domain currently locked?

Comment: They may be a reseller for another domain provider.  Check your domain's whois information as it may be set to the parent registrar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! They either transferred it or it was a child registar of enom.com. @CoryKnutson, you answered first, if you'd like the rep please post an answer.

Comment: A domain name could not exist anymore if the registrar does not exist. In such cases, in gTLDs, it already happened in the past, and domain names are transfered to another registrar, per ICANN rules. Also, if you did provide the domain name right in your question, people would have been able to better help you, especially since you like many others confuse registrars with their resellers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the current public registrar via the WhoIS info. Pull that information via a site like [https://who.is](http://who.is)